# how to call 2 methods or properties in ngmodel using angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

here i am using an input

```
 <input #dt id="{{dat.name}} " type="{{details.type}} " [(ngModel)]="Data[select][dat.name] " class="form-control ">
```

here my issue is how can i use another property in [(ngModel)] like

`[(ngModel)]="Data[select][dat.name] ;info[data.name]"` is it possible ?
 i need to invoke another functionality also by using the another property

Comment: What behavior are you trying to achieve? The input element has only one value.

Comment: nb: your interpolations should be : `[id]="dat.name" [type]="detailes.type"`

Comment: @Ploppy we can choose any thing right either property or template binding as per my requirement i choose template

Comment: @ConnorsFan here i want to get the input data where the first propety is invokes another function and thats why i need another property to use in ngmodel

Comment: You can bind only one property with `ngModel`. However, you can call another method when the value changes, with something like `(ngModelChange)="processData($event, info[data.name])"` (where `$event` is the bound value). Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: OK but ngModel i have to  please check this url https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xnbzqd  in this i have mentioned ng model but with out this i want to perfrom the same functionality

Comment: @ConnorsFan check the directives file where i m taking the ng moel instead of that is ther  any alternative

Answer (score 0):

you can bind the change event to a handler function with

```
(change)="updateProperties()"
```

and update any data / perform any functionality in that function